# HTML editor with jQuery/Selector like operations?

Tags: html, html-editor, jquery

Are there any HTML editors supporting jQuery-like selectors?

Such an editor would allow you to modify or delete all tags with a specified id or class.

It would be easier to use for HTML than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really meant as an editor, but your web browser can probably do this job well. Most web browsers allow you access to the JS console, so you can simply do your HTML editing there:

I'll use Chrome as an example.

Say you have your file (`index.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <p>Networking whiteboard authentic functionalities synergies cross-platform sticky global back-end robust, deliverables tag dynamic methodologies e-markets markets: widgets Cluetrain niches podcasts. Standards-compliant; deliverables embrace end-to-end channels cutting-edge reinvent engineer B2B paradigms tag synthesize life-hacks methodologies dynamic.
    </p>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Include jQuery in your HTML file and open it in your web browser. In Chrome, right click and open **Inspect Element** (Ctrl-Shift-I). The **Console** tab opens the JS console and allows you to execute jQuery commands:

[image]

Other features of this "*editor*" include **element highlighting**

[image]

and having your HTML/CSS edits rendered instantly, looking exactly like what you'll see in your web browser

[image]